# AMD loading widgets using Dojo 1.7

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've created a widget which I want to load via AMD in dojo 1.7. I want to be able to place my custom widgets libs on the same level as the dojo folder.

It appears that it always uses the base path of dojo and so need to put widgets inside the dojo folder, however libs that come with dojo doesnt need to follow that rule eg dijit and dojox.

I've tried changing the base path and a

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async:true
        //,baseUrl: '../src/js'
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('start1');
    require(
        ["dojo/ready"
         ,"dijit/Tree"
         ,"screeningResults/ScreeningResults"
        ],
        function(ready,tree, screening){
            var screeningUI = new screening({}, "screeningUI");
            screeningUI.startup();
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: You need to show us how your directories are being organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing your directory structure is like this :

- dojo/dijit
- dojo/dojox
- dojo/dojo
- src/js/mymodule

You should do :

```
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: true,
        async:true
        packages : [{name : 'mymodule', location : '/src/js/mymodule'}]
    };
</script>
```

Comment: In 1.7 amd, you need to use the "aliases" path

Comment: Actually I tried and managed to get it working by using packages, as Ken pointed out... I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to use the "aliases" parameter and pass in an array of the aliases inside another array. example in http://jsfiddle.net/tr_grc/ZVaRZ/

Comment: `aliases` generally isn't the right tool for this job; it is intended to remap individual module IDs.  The recommended property to play with would be `packages`.  See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/loader/amd.html#module-identifiers